# is there a way to set @EnableConfigurationProperties from config.xml?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm forking off from our current solution based on Spring Batch, and it's configured from `config.xml`. I wonder if there is a possibility to make `@EnableConfigurationProperties`-like functionality enabled from `config.xml` without setting `@SpringBootApplication` and moving towards annotation driven configuration?

The issue is that my class doesn't pickup values from `application.properties` without uncommenting lines.

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MappingConfiguration {
//    @Value("${used_attributes}")
    private List<String> usedAttributes;

//    @Value("${disabled_ou}")
    private String disabledOu;
```